# Carry-lookahead adder - what happens to carry bit?

Tags: adder, carry-look-ahead

I recreated and trying to understand for the sake of fun and learning the circuit that can be seen here on second page: [Link](http://writphotec.com/mano4/Supplements/Carrylookahead_supp4.pdf) . This is basically a 4-bit carry-lookahead adder, but there is one thing that I cannot understand. If there will be 1111 and carry bit will be 1, it looks like there is no way to pass a carry to the next unit. Turning carry bit on and off is irrelevant for the output (I mean here output information about carry). Maybe I'm missing something/recreated it wrong or some logic is in the "carry output" unit, anyone could explain it, and show how should connections between that kind of adders should look like? :)

You can download this circuit recreated in CEDAR Logic Simulator [Here](http://www.bigupload.com/en/file/53338/lookahead.cdl.html) .

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The carry input for each adder subunit (marked "PFA") is located on the *bottom* of the subunit schematic. It gets injected via the ripple carry subunit, which is duplicated for each adder unit.</s>

Now I see what the issue is.

The reason the CLC has G and P outputs is for cascading into another CLC so that higher-order carries can be looked ahead (lookaheaded?). However:

> If there are only four bits in the adder, then the
>   logic circuit used for C<sub>1</sub> can be used to generate C<sub>4</sub> from these two outputs; we will
>   later refer to the C<sub>1</sub> logic block as OC (Output Carry) for generating the output
>   carry from an adder, in this case, C<sub>4</sub>.

So, you need to duplicate the AND and OR gates at the LSb of the CLC in order to get C<sub>4</sub> from G<sub>0-3</sub> and P<sub>0-3</sub>.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine the connections, do you maybe have some graphics of circuits (or links), or could make one based on my cdl file? That would help not only me :) .

Comment: You mean the connection between C4 of the previous adder unit and C0 of the next?

Comment: Yep, exactly :) .

Comment: But... that's... just a single wire...

Comment: Well, not in a case of my circuit, you will see, that there is ONE input for carry and TWO outputs besides of 4 bits, and yet in certain situation, carry is not outputting even if I think it should, hence my question. You should look at the circuit I'm referencing :) .

Comment: If your circuit doesn't match what's in the PDF then you've done it wrong.

Comment: It's possible that I'm making some stupid mistake, as I don't have proper education, and trying to figure this out by myself, but this circuit seems to have two "outputs" (besides the actual 4-bit result) - one named G0-3 and one named P0-3, so the question is - where it leads, and how connects to other units, as clearly there is only one "carry input" in this unit.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it, so I just need to use the same pattern that I used inside of this units to connect 1-bit adders :) . Something like recursion. Thanks, now I got it! :)